# ENV.fetch vs secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5

I've a question about the best practice with environment variables for projects that are committed to GitHub or share between people.

When I started with rails I stored all my keys in the `secrets.yml` file. Then I figure this wasn't a good way when it's committed to GitHub. So what I did is to migrate my ENV variables to a .env file (with the help of a GEM loading them) and to access then with `ENV.fetch('MY_KEY')`.

When the app is on heroku, I don't need the GEM as heroku has his own system for ENV variables. So it works well for me, but I still wonder something:

As for an habit, I still put in my secrets the sensitive ones. For example, if I use stripe, I will store the `private key` and the publishable key in my `.env`. Load the publishable key from my code directly with `ENV.fetch('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY')` but for the private key, I still load it from the ENV to the secrets and then use the secrets:

```
default: &default
  stripe_secret_key: <%= ENV.fetch("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY") %>

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default

staging:
  <<: *default
```

Should I load all the ENV in it or should I stop using the secrets file?